# forcing mat-form-field to output a name or id

Tags: angular, angular-directive

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="firstName" />
</mat-form-field>
```

outputs this abomination:

```
<div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c125-1">
    <input _ngcontent-sfi-c379="" matinput="" formcontrolname="firstName" required="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c125-1 cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-dirty ng-touched ng-invalid" ng-reflect-required="" ng-reflect-name="dealerName" id="mat-input-0" aria-required="true"><span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c125-1">
        <label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c125-1 ng-star-inserted mat-empty mat-form-field-empty" ng-reflect-disabled="true" id="mat-form-field-label-1" ng-reflect-ng-switch="true" for="mat-input-0" aria-owns="mat-input-0">
            <mat-label _ngcontent-sfi-c379="" class="ng-tns-c125-1 ng-star-inserted">First Name</mat-label>
        </label>
    </span>
</div>
```

You'll note this part of the output: `id="mat-input-0"`. I would really like it to instead either output `id="firstName"` or, leave the id the same and add a name attribute to the input (eg `name="firstName"`. I can manually add the id (or name) attribute to the input field in the angular markup and it renders correctly, but I really don't want to have to explicitly add it for all 4000 input fields all over the app.

Why do I want this? Because my form auto fill (for test data) can only look at name or id fields and I don't want to have to be so darn specific all the time.

Comment: maybe building such directive will help you with generating the proper id as you wish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom [attribute directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) and re-use the existing `formControlName` attribute as selector to avoid adding an `id` or `name` attribute to all 4000 inputs:

```ts
@Directive({
    selector: 'input[formControlName]'
})
export class MyFormControlNameDirective {

    constructor(
        elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>,
        @Attribute('formControlName') name: string
    ) {
        const el = elementRef.nativeElement;
        if (!el.hasAttribute('name')) {
            el.setAttribute('name', name);
        }
    }
}
```